# ToolBar not work

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar

I'm not very good in code but I want to do a little app.
I just want to reset the toolbar but thats not work, i found many solution on internet but I don't understand anything ...

My code :

*MainActivity.java*

```
package r.antoine.gestionbbox;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webview;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        webview .getSettings() .setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl("http://gestionbbox.lan/login.html");
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

}
```

*Activity_main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="r.antoine.gestionbbox.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Thank You for help

Comment: What does it mean to reset toolbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya thats too choosy to solve out

1. Use AppCompatActivity instead of Activity
2. If you are using Android Studio use gradle compile

> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

3. Make styles.xml file with value

   ```
       <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

       </style>
   ```
4. In manifest in application tag use

> ```
> <application
>         android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
> ```

Comment: Okay, I have the name, now hot to change the color ?

Comment: ya your english is really awesome Jokes part: use attribute **android:background="#d3d3d3"**

Comment: i want to write how no hot ^^

Comment: Sorry but i'm a little null ...

How to attribute that ?

Comment: in your xml file just go to toolbar use clt+space it give you suggestion and use android:background="#d3d3d3" //here #d3d3d3 is hax code you can change it.

Comment: sorry but where i have to do ctrl+space ?

Comment: If you just like the answere than please upvote: Thank You

Comment: Hi, I need help for an other simple thing is it possible to discuss on private  ?

Comment: Ya why not that was my pleasure if I can help you out.

Comment: can i contact you on twitter ?

Comment: you can hangout me rajeshchandratiwari@gmail.com

Comment: i invite you on hangout

Answer (score 0):

Toolbar is just like any other widget. and what do you mean by reset the toolbar
so if you want to remove it just add

```
    android:visibility="gone"
```

or in java code use

```
    toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

or just completely delete it from the view if you are not going to use it.

for better understanding on toolbar read the documentation.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html

Comment: On the contrary, I would give it ^^

PS: sorry for my bad English is google translation ...

Answer (score 0):

In your **styles.xml** add this:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

right below "Customize your theme here." if you want to show your toolbar.
Theme style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```